# dual display problems on ubuntu 15.10 with amd r9 380

Tags: unity, ati, display

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 15.10 and when I first booted the computer I was only one of my two displays was turned on. So I decided to intsall the ampgpu patched 4.3 Kernel and that allowed both displays to turn but when I tried changing the display settings it crashed and I got the following output from the terminal

** (unity-control-center:4120): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "displays"
**
ERROR:gsd-rr-config.c:661:gsd_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gsd_rr_config_match (config, config))
Aborted (core dumped)

Thanks for the help and cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem as you do. Installing the proprietary drivers, like the Internet suggested, didn't help one bit (it caused even more problems).

I've found that this problem only occurs when using HDMI + DVI, not when using HDMI + DisplayPort. So, that kinda solves it for me..